# Map Enum to user choice checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, checkbox, enums

At present I have the following

```
if ((int)dpRepeatType.SelectedValue == (int)Constants.RepeatType.Weekly)
{
                 wrule = new WeeklyRecurrenceRule(Convert.ToDateTime(dtDateStart.Value),WeekDays.Monday, 1);
                _newAppointment.RecurrenceRule = wrule.ToString();

}
```

On Screen I have 7 checkboxes representing the days of the week. Sunday to Sat My question is WeekDay is an internal enum of telerik rad scheduler based on the following.

My Question is insteads of doing a tone of if statements on individual checkboxes to see which day or days the user has select which can be more than one,  how can i do this with linq at present I am doing it with if statements but I am sure there a better way.

```
[Flags]
    public enum WeekDays
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies none of the days
        None = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the first day of the week
        Sunday = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the second day of the week
        Monday = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the third day of the week
        Tuesday = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the fourth day of the week
        Wednesday = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the fifth of the week
        Thursday = 16,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the sixth of the week
        Friday = 32,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the work days of the week
        WorkDays = 62,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the seventh of the week
        Saturday = 64,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the weekend days of the week
        WeekendDays = 65,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies every day of the week
        EveryDay = 127
    }
}
```

This is what the ui is like to what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that the only `CheckBox` controls in your form are the ones concerning te week days and their `Name` property follows the pattern below:

```
CheckBoxMonday
CheckBoxTuesday
...
```

One solution could be the following one:

```
WeekDays wd = WeekDays.None;

foreach (CheckBox checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{   
    if (checkBox.IsChecked)
        wd |= (WeekDays)Enum.Parse(typeof(WeekDays), checkBox.Name.Replace("CheckBox", ""));

}
```

Demo code [here](http://rextester.com/YNIPW90431).

Comment: Thanks for answering today how would I turn that then into the Weekdays or does that converstion at the start do that

Comment: Also what if other controls of type checkbox on form would this not fail in that case.

Comment: The conversion is already returning a `WeekDays` enum with the proper flags set according to the selected checkboxes.

Comment: If you have other checkboxes in your form, the best is to define a common pattern in their names so you can select them propery. You could add a prefix like "WD_CheckBoxMonday" so you know that you must select those whose name starts with "WD_".

Comment: Using `LINQ` you can also use the following one liner: `List<WeekDays> wds = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => (WeekDays)Enum.Parse(typeof(WeekDays), x.Name.Replace("CheckBox", ""))).ToList();` but you still have to merge them into a single flag enum.

Comment: Its only one day they are allowed to repeat on so the first one will again many thanks for aisstance.